# MS Graph get report failed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to get report like this

```
var report = await ServiceClient.Reports.GetMailboxUsageStorage("D7").Request().GetAsync();
```

But it fails with 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
at Microsoft.Graph.Serializer.DeserializeObject[T](String inputString)
at Microsoft.Graph.ResponseHandler.HandleResponse[T](HttpResponseMessage response)
at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)

What's wrong? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Let me know if still face any issue on this.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue in the Microsoft Graph SDK, so you can use the HttpClient and get the data by using the following code.

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken); 
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("reports/getMailboxUsageStorage(period='D7')");
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
```

You could see the results as below.

[image]

Comment: Is this "issue in the Microsoft Graph SDK" being fixed at some point?